# urllib2.openurl not working on Google Patents

Tags: python, urllib2, urlopen

I'm trying to scrape some data from google patents, and the beginning of my code looks like this: ([here](http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&q=ininventor:%22John-Mudd%22&hl=en&tbm=pts&source=lnt&tbs=ptso:us) is the hyperlink to the url listed below)

```
In [1]: import urllib2

In [2]: url='http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&q=ininventor:\"{}\"&hl=en&tbm=pts&source=lnt&tbs=ptso:us'.format('John-Mudd')

In [3]: print url
http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&q=ininventor:"John-Mudd"&hl=en&tbm=pts&source=lnt&tbs=ptso:us

In [4]: page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

Which throws the error message:

```
C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in urlopen(url, data, timeout)
    124     if _opener is None:
    125         _opener = build_opener()
--> 126     return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    127 
    128 def install_opener(opener):

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    404         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    405             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 406             response = meth(req, response)
    407 
    408         return response

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in http_response(self, request, response)
    517         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    518             response = self.parent.error(
--> 519                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    520 
    521         return response

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in error(self, proto, *args)
    442         if http_err:
    443             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 444             return self._call_chain(*args)
    445 
    446 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    376             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
    377 
--> 378             result = func(*args)
    379             if result is not None:
    380                 return result

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    525 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    526     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 527         raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    528 
    529 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Not sure why I'm getting this.

EDIT:

trying it with `urllib.openurl` instead gets me a little further:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: import urllib

In [3]: url='https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&q=ininventor:"Alan-Mudd"&hl=en&tbm=pts&source=lnt&tbs=ptso:us'

In [4]: print url
https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&q=ininventor:"John-Mudd"&hl=en&tbm=pts&source=lnt&tbs=ptso:us

In [5]: page=urllib.urlopen(url)

In [6]: txt=BeautifulSoup(page).get_text()

In [7]: txt
Out[7]: u'htmlError 403 (Forbidden)!!1*{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}403. That\u2019s an error.Your client does not have permission to get URL /search?tbo=p&q=ininventor:%22John-Mudd%22&hl=en&tbm=pts&source=lnt&tbs=ptso:us from this server.  (Client IP address: 68.112.246.242)\nPlease see Google\'s Terms of Service posted at http://www.google.com/terms_of_service.html\nIf you believe that you have received this response in error, please report your problem. However, please make sure to take a look at our Terms of Service (http://www.google.com/terms_of_service.html). In your email, please send us the entire code displayed below.  Please also send us any information you may know about how you are performing your Google searches-- for example, "I\'m using the Opera browser on Linux to do searches from home.  My Internet access is through a dial-up account I have with the FooCorp ISP." or "I\'m using the Konqueror browser on Linux to search from my job at myFoo.com.  My machine\'s IP address is 10.20.30.40, but all of myFoo\'s web traffic goes through some kind of proxy server whose IP address is 10.11.12.13."  (If you don\'t know any information like this, that\'s OK.  But this kind of information can help us track down problems, so please tell us what you can.)We will use all this information to diagnose the problem, and we\'ll hopefully have you back up and searching with Google again quickly!\nPlease note that although we read all the email we receive, we are not always able to send a personal response to each and every email.  So don\'t despair if you don\'t hear back from us!\nAlso note that if you do not send us the entire code below, we will not be able to help you.Best wishes,The Google Team/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/+/\nDVEH8IymbCoo1dGrTzyT1iwqSLxjtFu0V4uU5kLrZ7OjChn7z\nLh5w5aLlP6v5piIZSC7_8OTKEepHBTROurNwIOVtc7sH0UTJL\n6mOs5-a-s4X63WfAUM064ZFl9JGwBR6VMKvdyMQOoYo7WtAGI\nbcVTsj7H3uWatFa4O9Zuxs7IcRQLOCiWwwhQs-s2AoAiFKlGN\nyXaTCO8GfhXxBt5JYCrTx-mkyrtqDqG_yvNu-fPYTf7V7jLNK\ntgwnPMBejraU_xbwSzoWNx2z7SfDmbPncbwSAMNnZ2CfiMhp8\ns1LQK90rg5hYAgbLmoVjMHMZ0WeRoay-XoB1oKQzff-nnkAEy\nuULx-MidjfVeuQfChSHMY3HUZ13vvzOsJZUjF-GH_-uymoPRG\n5RUBeodyOO3x9cJ-0mvHC_TyAwog10cRwaGKdS-DO92moJem0\nEoUKjmHuF4wXPcbGlSh_GXC9rFM07K6ZR4DxrV27iRaBZmen_\naw_l0qXlfK8quX7qAJT9W2EcrDRDYZdiNnBw7DdpLGeTCK76E\n0KCimiCY1uKC6kkdbGfFjQPK0R-_8DtBE5k7_MwgPR5O-sT0w\nf-ZH0vyEHSor4N8ZCogRMH_mR9L8hB2vrT5HWmYNJbLxS3SjB\nZHeL2vErN6jDFdpTFN7rPKU3-hnP-3zevYMUhHMFSPsi9ShZ7\nddrhqBhbdzifrwC4RgGbsqKTMMUERaoRJC9jj4jrNd14PlOpa\nztAa_82MQ1FhUswXO0EJ6dOHL6NknoBWOYN2-IFT_7cvAbxV6\nofoYL_y5WihMeZpDBPnpRyhjxjAefxNdzA5h9bE5GqV9ZoS92\n4q3Q81-0WK0kmloyf019Y5fI8Ln7ooJFzNpW5Fa7ezHhJ1Yxh\nHLNlD8dLFZogHDrtHsvWOzPWjYESdflsnJ5TjSijnt8ZGF_eT\ncZy50Pt4AFMsVUC3Dn4jkkzv-tok_1WgLKrEqpzzc55Hc4fOq\n9zdSYk52EH0R4__7fJ0w8ZfGmU4x1qGGDatZNpJRpSpLIJjXw\ntJPiGXllFPqQIFfWjIk3WubYKUJOHW37IyIJFjT-yVn6YgESl\nVe2nKpc1FBV1lSyhz5aW-QZtu_tCgPfG4gbfUCPYk54XBgNL4\n6a034xtD5a3rlRw1_ZnBCi7962YybZhX9MKXq5x6Au-y3Fqgg\nxzqicRlQ9UUso0fQ4JJRrLv57OuS2VvpaDCvN8pU1YQOSQWeX\niD1eqxMVoQ35ZaoCYlr-SBaRPuiwett9Fk6EZkvEWL1JqAiQq\n6k_PQ7hoISsoBSYSg1ztYV43JFfZLt1PE_geCPOb7XgUE5rVf\nQPHQX48cKjZmlrzYUyXS_BGSqZOPxZoj7ANivSn5vE88b74wH\ndoybElt_BVmigcY
```

The error message in it's entirety is shown in this image.

[image: Snapshot of error message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems Google are blocking some crawlers.

codingatty pointed out it doesn't work when the user agent string is `'Python'`.
Base on my experiment, the following user agent strings do not work either(Obviously, this list is incomplete).

- Alexibot
- HTTrack
- wget

Since `urllib2`'s default user agent string is `'Python-urllib/2.7'` (on Python 2.7), you need to set `User-Agent` header to a common web browser or a fake one.

For example:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&q=ininventor:"John-Mudd"&hl=en&tbm=pts&source=lnt&tbs=ptso:us'
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "foobar"})
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. Have time for a brief rationale on why that worked?

Comment: @Chris: Without `User-Agent`, your program is disallowed to access patents. See http://www.google.com/robots.txt

Comment: Interestingly, I found that {'User-Agent' : "foobar"} (as above) or {'User-Agent' : "python"} work, but {'User-Agent' : "Python"} (with upper-case 'P') does not, although there's no reference to it in the robots.txt.

Comment: @codingatty: [Robots.txt instructions are directives only](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en) . Neither crawlers nor web servers have the obligation to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `https` protocol instead of `http`:

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/?tbm=pts#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&tbm=pts&sclient=psy-ab&q=John-Mudd&oq=John-Mudd&gs_l=hp.12..0i30j0i10i30j0i30j0i10i30.3253.6396.0.10231.9.8.0.1.1.0.81.406.8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.q-r2I_BIxrw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44011176,d.cGE&fp=ef59fd2c4e6518f1&biw=1162&bih=927'
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error, were you able to pull it successfully?

Comment: Yes, the http result in 403, while https pulls through.